# Pass credit card information in Laravel for 3DSecure

Tags: php, laravel, payment, 3d-secure

I am developing a website with a payment module and I need to handle 3Dsecure and have a question about the good method to do it.

I am developing with Php and Laravel but I think it is a general question.

I firstly make a request to 3DSecure server to know if the card uses the service. In this request I passe the card information (name, number, expiration date, cvv ...).
The server gives me a response with a md code and a pareq code after redirecting on another url of my website.

On this url I have a new code pares. And then I must make a payment request with this code + the card information.

Problem is since the user gives me the card information in a form, on this page (where 3DS redirects) I don't have the card information anymore.

I see a solution : I could pass the card information in an encrypted cookie but I am not sure it's the best practice.

Anyone knows what is the best solution for this ?

EDIT :

- would it be more secure to store it in database (also encrypted of course) ?
- would it be better to encrypt it with a unique encryption key ? that I would store in database ? (I would encrypt the unique key with a general key for the website)

Thank you

Comment: When you want to handle credit card information your server needs to fulfill a huge amount of security measures. It is probably easier to use an external service that does this for you like [Stripe](https://stripe.com/). I'm not affiliated with stripe.

Comment: I know. I have highly recommended my client to use Stripe but he wants its own payment service. Should I trust Laravel encryption ?

Comment: You should NOT store CC details unless you comply with [PCI DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pci_security/) standards, unfortunately I can't answer your question because I don't know how to implement such level of security